# How to attach an external js-vue file with an html file

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, external-js

i am trying to attach an external js file with my html code to run vue code but i'm getting errors like element not found and vue not declared .

i have tried jsfiddle but it doesn't solve my problem

});[As you can see this is a basic code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvQ9f.png)

Comment: did you already solved ? i need to / looking for running html only on vue without root body that has on compile / listening by npm .

Answer (score 0):

Your `main.js` needs to look something like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

You are missing the actual `App` component, you need a `App.vue` as well (or at least a template).
Try this:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '<div>{{title}}</div>',
  data: {title: 'success'}
})
```